# Building OpenCV from source for ROS

Tags: opencv, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in need of a newer version or OpenCV than is provided by my Ubuntu repo. Is there a version or fork of OpenCV that contains a package.xml so it can be compiled as part of a ROS workspace? Seems like that would be more convenient than compiling a local version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327429/building-opencv-from-source-for-ros/) by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2019-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May or may not be an answer but this doesn't fit into comment section so posting as an answer.

Building `opencv` from source for ROS is documented [on this section on its wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3#Building_the_Package), which seems to cover not just building from source but mixed with how to make binary packages out of built artifact IINM. I haven't tried the whole steps by myself, but I'd say go through the steps in that section up to the following line, then start building:

```
44 echo "install(FILES package.xml DESTINATION share/opencv3)" >> ./CMakeLists.txt
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2019-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) on 2019-07-02**:
Thanks 130s. I had stopped looking at that page about 24 hours ago because I found the instructions confusing and it all looked pretty outdated. I just took another stab at it, changing the OpenCV version to 2.4.6 and using opencv3-release's package.xml for lunar because there isn't one for melodic.

All that gets me a package that compiles in my workspace. Yay! Problem solved.

Unfortunately, now I'm stuck on a different problem: [not all libraries link against my local OpenCV](https://answers.ros.org/question/327506/compiling-stereo_image_proc-with-local-opencv/). I get the exact same problem now building OpenCV in my workspace. Ug.